# Show taxonomy child before parent

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a taxonomy configured as hierarchical categories, and it happens that when I create a post and select the category parent and child, when I give the parent appears first, follow the code I'm using, for a better explanation:

```
<?ph

    $local = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'fornecedor_localidade');

    $parent_id = $local[0]->parent;
    $parent = get_term_by( 'id', $parent_id, 'fornecedor_localidade' );

    echo $local[0]->name. '/' .$parent->slug;

?>
```

Today it looks like this:

**PARENT/CHILD**

And I wanted it to look like this:

**CHILD/PARENT**

I do not know what system Wordpress interprets to sort the categories, but I tried everything and I could not, I'm waiting for some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple way, reverse `get_the_terms` result.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/

```
$local = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'fornecedor_localidade');
if ($local && !is_wp_error($local)) {
    $local = clone (object)array_reverse((array)$local);
    $local_names = array();
    foreach ($local as $term)
        $local_names[] = $term->name;
    $locals = implode(" / ", $local_names);
    echo $locals;
}
```

Another way:

```
$local = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'fornecedor_localidade');
if ($local && !is_wp_error($local)) {
    $local_names = array();
    foreach ($local as $term)
        $local_names[$term->term_id] = $term->parent==0 ? $term->slug : $term->name;
    ksort($local_names);
    $locals = implode(" / ", array_reverse($local_names));
    echo $locals;
}
```

Comment: Your response is not wrong, but what is happening is that sometimes the order changes, sometimes it happens that the parent comes in front and sometimes not, I wanted a way to always force CHILD first and then the PARENT

Comment: This category contains the Brazilian cities and states, so I want it to stay as CITY / STATE, state is actually the state code. Example: São Paulo / SP

Comment: Seems to be working, only has one detail, no way to put the state as slug? In case you are picking up the NAME field, I need this: Child (name) / Parent (slug)

Comment: If parent without parent!
$local_names[$term->term_id] = $term->parent==0 ? $term->slug : $term->name;